# WCF: The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded

Tags: .net, wcf

Ok, I have no idea what is going on. I've found a bunch of posts here and from googling, but they all say pretty much the same thing: change the maxStringContentLength in both client and server. I've done that and much more but I still am getting the same damn error. I've also tried changing the max length programatically but no dice.

Web.config on server:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="320" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:52826/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
      contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">        
  </endpoint>
</client>


<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="wsServiceBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

and on client:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:52826/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

I also noticed that when I run the service. the config file that is generated lists maxStringContentLength = "8192". I've tried turning off the option to "Always regenerate config file when launching services" and editing the config file directly to increase the max, but it still doesn't work.

--EDIT--
It appears that the service isn't actually picking up the config as mentioned by Eugune. I added in:

```
    <services>
  <service name="Courrier.myService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:52826/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="ServiceReference1.IService1">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

but still not working?

Answer (score 3):

When I see this error on the client, it usually means that the service threw an exception. If you have show errors turned on for the web service, the stack trace in an exception can easily blow out the 8192 string limit.

Comment: I'm reading in a text file into a string and sending it to the service. The length count is ~11k. When I hard code in a string instead of reading the file, everything works fine. So I don't think an error is being thrown.

Comment: @user850237 - Can you post the code where you read the text file into a string?  It's possible something in that code is throwing an exception whereas hard-coding the string won't.

Comment: I really don't think that is it. I'm doing the reading of the file on the client side, into a string and then sending it.
ServiceReference1.Service1Client sc = new Service1Client();
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(emailPath);                
var inputEmail = tr.ReadToEnd();
var emailSend = sc.SendEMail(fromEmailAddress, subject, inputEmail, toEmailAddress, "nothing", url, true, 32, 100, 100);

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you actually changed the quotas on the server? In your "server" config, you define a BasicHttpBinding_IService1 binding with increased quotas, but then you only use it in the <client> section.

Comment: I think this may be it. It doesn't appear the service is picking up the config I created and is resorting to the default. I edited my original question to add in what I've added to the server config file, but it's still not working?